# How to make unordered lists selectable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-app

I have got List of Unordered lists from server.How to make each unordered list selectable injavasript

here am getting list of of ip addresses in my server. I need to make each list item clicable

```
results.classList.remove('working');

if (opt_error) {
  var s = document.createElement('strong');
  s.classList.add('warning');
  s.innerText = opt_error;
  results.appendChild(s);
  return console.warn(opt_error);
}

var outer = finder.services;
var inner = finder.ips;

// TODO: render information about outer/inner
// for IPs, render 'last seen at...'
// for services, render known service type.

results.innerHTML = '';
outer.apply(finder).forEach(function(o) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = getHtml_(outer, o);
  results.appendChild(li);

  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  inner.call(finder, o).forEach(function(i) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = getHtml_(inner, i);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
  ul.childNodes.length && results.appendChild(ul);
});
};
```

Comment: What does "selectable" mean?  Are you sure you don't want to use a `<select>` element?

Comment: A sample code would be very useful.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kana7xav/?

Comment: i need to make each list item clickable to submit the list information

Comment: What is "to submit the list information".  Seriously here, you need to do a much, much better job describing what you are trying to accomplish if you want help here.  We don't know what you want to do.  StackOverflow works great if you write a clear, concise question that fully describes what you're trying to accomplish, shows us what you have tried so far and explains where you got stuck.  It doesn't work at all if you can't convey to us what you're trying to do.

Comment: results.innerHTML = '';
    outer.apply(finder).forEach(function(o) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = getHtml_(outer, o);
      results.appendChild(li);
          
      var ul = document.createElement('ul');
      inner.call(finder, o).forEach(function(i) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = getHtml_(inner, i);
        ul.appendChild(li);
      });
      ul.childNodes.length && results.appendChild(ul);
    });
  };

Comment: Please use the edit link beneath your question to add this code and explanation to your question.  Multi line code is not readable in comments.  Your goal here is edit your question until it is clear so people have enough information in the question to help you.  The info should be in the question, not in the comments.  Also, I posted a link to a selectable unordered list.  Is that what you want?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mdibbets/hsjn77uv/44/ is something i have written and I use it regularly. Is this kinda what you have in mind?

Comment: yes, but i wont add components to display in list. The values in list are discovered programatically to get ip address from server.

Comment: In your foreach loops you could use <element just appended>.onClick = <your function to call when clicked>